# Already finished 89 confirmation still not received in my Electrum 2fa wallet

Tags: blockchain.info

I sent Bitcoin from localbitcoin wallet to my electrum wallet. Now it's 89 confirmation done. But still now it's not arrived in my wallet. Please help. Thank You  Electrum wallet address :- 3FE82ud16Zgts5gWR8zP7CgxHGLaHqxJWr  ... Txid:-5c6527b1a3b1d99a03c140907c00b0953083bdb3af1a3e7587549ddd9a230ac0[image]

Comment: I can verify that the transaction is confirmed, so there must be some issue with your wallet syncing to the Bitcoin network. Are you sure it is in sync?

Comment: Yes. It is syncing. I changed it's server many time . Now it's in automatic mode. Also I restored wallet with my seed. Still not received bits in my wallet.

Comment: Give it time to sync, as long as the seed phrase you have can derive the address you've listed, your coins are safe. You just need a wallet that is properly synced to the network to be able to spend the funds.

Comment: I added a photo of my wallet. Do I need to put my wallet online for receive Bitcoin?

Comment: You can receive to an address without needing your wallet to be online, but in order for your wallet to then display your updated balance or spend the bitcoin, it will need to go online to sync with the network.